# OpenGl - Texture, Framebuffer update

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I'm trying to render a frame captured on OpenCV using OpenGL (imshow is too slow), however I'm failing to update the texture with each new frame. I know I could use GPU on OpenCV but I just don't want to rebuild it, I also thought it should be pretty easy to render it on OpenGL.

The following is the code I'm working on - It should be pretty straight forward yet I don't know where I'm messing up.

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

void render();
void initFrame();
void createTexture();


GLuint textureId;
GLuint fb;
int width = 400;
int height = 400;
VideoCapture cap;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width);
  cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height);
  if(!cap.open(0))
    exit(-1);

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

  glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
  glutCreateWindow("Test");
  glutDisplayFunc(render);
  glutIdleFunc(glutPostRedisplay);


  createTexture();
  initFrame();
  glutMainLoop(); 
  return 0;

}

void createTexture()
{
  //create texture id
  glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, //Type of texture
               0,             //pyramid level (for mip-mapping) - 0: top level
               GL_RGB,        //Internal color format to convert to
               width,      //Image width
               height,      //Image height
               0,             //border width in pix (either 1 or 0)  
               GL_RGB,        //Input image format
               GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,// Image data type
               0         // image data
              );
  /*
  else if(mat.channels() == 4)
  {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, //Type of texture
                 0,             //pyramid level (for mip-mapping) - 0: top level
                 GL_RGBA,        //Internal color format to convert to
                 width,      //Image width
                 height,      //Image height
                 0,             //border width in pix (either 1 or 0)  
                 GL_RGBA,        //Input image format
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,// Image data type
                 0        // image data
                );

  }
  */
  //free(imgPtr);
  //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
  glFlush();
}

void initFrame()
{
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
}


void render()
{
  Mat frame;
  cap >> frame;

  if(frame.empty())
    exit(-1);

  glTexSubImage2D(textureId,
                  0,
                  0,
                  0,
                  frame.cols,
                  frame.rows,
                  GL_RGB,
                  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  frame.ptr()
                  );

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
  glFlush();
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);


  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glViewport(0,0,width,height);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

  glLoadIdentity();

  gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

  glLoadIdentity();

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  float cube[][2]   = {
                        {-1, -1},
                        { 1, -1},
                        { 1,  1},
                        {-1,  1}
                      };

  float textCor[][2] = {
                          {0,0},
                          {1,0},
                          {1,1},
                          {0,1}
                        };
  unsigned int faces[] = {1,0,3,2};

  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

  glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 2*sizeof(float), &cube[0][0]);
  glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 2*sizeof(float), &textCor[0][0]);

  glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
  glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, faces);

  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
  glFlush();

  glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

Comment: Why are you culling front faces? Or, why are you enabling culling in the first place? You're only drawing one quad. Not sure what you would want to cull. There's some other code you don't need, you're making this much more complicated than necessary. No need for an index array if you're using each vertex only once, just put them in the right order. And what are you trying to achieve with the `glFramebufferTexture2D()` call?

Comment: I was culling the back face but I noticed my image was flipping, so I went and culled the front face (I'll fix that later). As for the  glFramebufferTexture2D , I 'm trying to attach the texture image to a frame buffer object. I'm new to OpenGL, and I'm just trying to render a texture minded to a frame picture as fast as possible.